# Editing users preferredLocale from a plugin controller

Tags: craft3, plugin-development, users

Recently upgrade from Craft 2 to Craft 3. Also had to update all the custom plugins.  Once of them is to run a daily import of users from a file.  In that file we try to set the preferredLocal of that users as we have 3 locales/sites.  Once I have created the user and try to update the preferredLocale as I did in craft 2 it fails out.

```
//I get a setting read-only property error in logs when I call it like this
$user->preferredLocale = "en_us";

//I get a setting unknown property error when I try it like this.  
$user->setFieldValue('preferredLocale', 'en_us');
```

I have looked around but not able to find how I can change the new or existing users preferred Locale so any help or examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user’s locale is considered a preference and is therefore stored in a separate `userpreferences` database table. As such, you cannot simply set it on a user element.

Instead, you can go through the [Users::saveUserPreferences()](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/c122b6d84f9c2421f798634c6e42a6eee1271b9a/src/services/Users.php#L344-L361) method as follows.

```php
Craft::$app->users->saveUserPreferences($user, ['locale' => 'en-US']);
```

For reference, this is called from the [UsersController](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/c122b6d84f9c2421f798634c6e42a6eee1271b9a/src/controllers/UsersController.php#L1440) class.